# Data annotation to check dependent property is value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

My requirement is to validate a field depending on Ajax return success or failure message. 
I have hidden property IsValidEmployeenumber is set 'true' or 'false' from Ajax call.

```
    [XXX('IsValidEmployeeNumber', 'true')]  //Please suggest
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    public string IsValidEmployeeNumber { get; set; }
```

May I know is there a native MVC data annotation available that will take dependent property name and expected value.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no such native annotation. You can make your own, which will take as a paramter the name of the property on which the validation depends, and then when applying, pass the appropriate property name.

The way to do this is to create a custom annotation class deriving from `ValidationAttribute`, and making a constructor which takes as a parameter the name of the dependent property, and then override the `IsValid` method, in which you get the value of the dependent property using reflection, and write your custom validation logic.

Now, this will work for server side validation. But you need to do a lot more if you need client side validation as well, which is beyond the scope of this question.